# Complex looping through groups of variables

Tags: python, macros, spss

I've got an SPSS dataframe looking like this:

```
K_161   K_161_A K_161_B K_161_B K_161_C K_161_D K_213
0   0   0   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   0   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   1   1   1
0   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   0   0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   1   1   1   1
0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0
1   1   0   1   0   1   1
0   1   0   0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   1   1   0   0
```

Basically I want to loop through the variables (columns) and return values for the reliability measure Cronbach's alpha. 
Something that would work along the lines of the following pseudocode in Python:

```
BEGIN PROGRAM.
import spss

unique_ids = open("E:/company_id.txt", "r")

for i in unique_ids:
  i = "K_" + str(i)
  spss.Submit(r'''
  RELIABILITY 
  /VARIABLES= + i
  /SCALE('ALL VARIABLES') ALL 
  /MODEL=ALPHA.
  ''')

END PROGRAM.
```

I've got about 9000 columns. The variables used in each loop can be grouped based on their unique number: e.g. for 161 the loop would include K_161 K_161_A K_161_B K_161_B K161_C K_161_D and so on. I've got a list of these unique numbers (textfile) looking like this:

```
161
213
263
284
295
297
306
347
```

The SPSS syntax returns a measure for Cronbach's alpha as well as the number of cases. I want to return a dataframe which looks like this:

```
id  cronbach    cases
161 0.651   5
213 0.856   3
263 0.752   6
284 0.927   22
295 0.884   24
297 0.934   31
306 0.902   9
347     1
398 0.405   4
457 0.884   12
491 0.137   2
507 0.909   28
571     1
590 0.738   9
```

I kind of lack the creativity to find the right solution here. Really looking for some ideas how you would approach the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'm creating two datasets to simulate your two files - one with your IDs and one with the actual data for analysis:

```
data list free/id (f3).
begin data
161  444 213
end data.
dataset name numlist.

data list free/K_161 K_161_A K_161_B K_213_B K_161_C K_161_D K_213 K_213_A K_444 K_444_F K_444_K (11f3).
begin data
3 3 3  4 4 4 5 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
end data.
dataset name main.
```

Now the Idea is to use the ID list to write a new syntax file.
For each item in the list, the new syntax will:
1. define a macro that finds all the corresponding variable names in the main file
2. run a reliability analysis on them.
The OMS command will capture the cronbach data from the output into another dataset:

```
DATASET DECLARE  MyAlphas.
OMS/SELECT TABLES/IF COMMANDS=['Reliability'] SUBTYPES=['Reliability Statistics']
   /DESTINATION FORMAT=SAV NUMBERED=TableNumber_ OUTFILE='MyAlphas' .
dataset activate numlist.
write out="path\temp macro run.sps" 
   /'SPSSINC SELECT VARIABLES MACRONAME = "!a', id, '" /PROPERTIES PATTERN=".*', id, '*".'
   /'RELIABILITY /VARIABLES= !a', id, '  /SCALE("ALL VARIABLES") ALL  /MODEL=ALPHA.'.
dataset activate main.
insert file="path\temp macro run.sps".
omsend.
```

At this point you have a dataset called `MyAlphas` which has the cronbach values for each reliability test that was run. It doesn't yet have the IDs in it, but it's easy enough to `match files` this dataset with the IDs list -
you can add an index number to the list and match it with `TableNumber_` in `MyAlphas`.